# Why does my promise return an array of [object] or [array]

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to loop through a list of urls from github's api and get a array back with all the information. What I am returned is an array with [object],[object] instead of the actual data.  I presume that it has something about my promise not resolving.

here is my function:

```
async function getCommitsByWeek() {
  const allRepoNames = await getRepos(user);
  const repoURLs = await allRepoNames.map(({ full_name, name }) => {
    return {
      name,
      url: `https://api.github.com/repos/${full_name}/stats/contributors`,
    };
  });

  const theStuff = await Promise.all(
    repoURLs.map(({ url, name }) =>
      axios.get(url, AUTH).then(({ data }) => {
        const info = data[0].weeks.map(week => {
          return { w: week.w, c: week.c };
        });
        //console.log(name, info);
        return { name, info };
      })
    )
  );
  return theStuff
}
```

this is what is expected

```
{ name: 'my-github-data_frontend',
  info: [ { w: 1555804800, c: 1 } ] }
{ name: 'Below-the-fold',
  info:
   [ { w: 1542499200, c: 2 },
     { w: 1543104000, c: 0 },
     { w: 1555200000, c: 0 },
     { w: 1555804800, c: 0 } ] }
{ name: 'contraction-app',
  info:
   [ { w: 1536451200, c: 9 },
     { w: 1537056000, c: 5 },
     { w: 1555200000, c: 0 },
     { w: 1555804800, c: 0 } ] }
```

and this is what I am getting currently

```
{ name: 'Below-the-fold',
    info:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object], ] },
  { name: 'contraction-app',
    info:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
```

Comment: That's just how the console shows it. Output it as JSON to be sure what it is.

Comment: Nit: no reason to `await allRepoNames.map` it's not a Promise. Other nit: use `async`/`await` everywhere - you can replace the `.then` with it

Answer (score 0):

That's just how the console is showing it. In your "what I'm expecting" you give an example of an array of objects.

The console output is showing an array of objects, but without giving the detail of each object.

If you want to force the console to show what's in each `info` object, you can use `console.log(name, JSON.stringify(info));`

As an aside, your `return theStuff` near the end of your code looks out of place. Not sure what that is doing.

Comment: the nodejs console is not interactive.

Comment: @JonasWilms I didn't notice the node.js tag. Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited my answer based on that.